# Using too many if blocks is good ? what are possible alternatives?

Tags: php, performance

I have been designing a shopping website lately in PHP. Now in Checkout page i have to check many times if the user is logged in. i.e If the user is logged in *hide the Signin div* and *show the Shipping div*.

```
<section class="panels <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo"unactivepanel"; else echo"activepanel";?>" id="Sign In">
        <div class="wrapper1" >
            <ul>
            <li><input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required/></li>
            <li class="inf">(will only be used for sending you order information.)</li>
            <fieldset><legend class="orb"> OR</legend>
            <li><input type="button" value="Sign In to booksmore" class="sb si llb" /></li></fieldset>
            <fieldset><legend class="orb"> OR</legend>
            <li>Sign In using any of following service:</li>
            <li>
                <div class="box1 fc">Facebook</div>
                <div class="box1 tw">Twitter</div>
                <div class="box1 gg">Google</div>
                <div class="box1 oi">Open Id</div>
            </li></fieldset>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="panels <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo"unactivepanel"; else echo"activepanel";?>unactivepanel" id="Shipping"></section>
    <section class="panels unactivepanel" id="Confirm"></section>
```

What i have studied is using too many **if** block slows down the executions speed, So am I right using too many **if** blocks ? if I am not coding it right(*what i feel right now*) then what may be the possible alternatives to **if** blocks ? (I was thinking of using **switch** block.)

Comment: I see 2 `ifs`, how is that too many?

Comment: Yes if you have too many if blocks then sswitch to "switch" statment is good

Comment: @LawrenceCherone there has to be atleast 5-6 ifs. i have not shown the whole code. I have mentioned it already that i have to verify that user is logged in many times.

Comment: Worry about whether your site may be slow **when your site is slow**. A handful of `if` statements certainly will not cause any measurable performance drop. Heck, *hundreds* of `if`s wouldn't cause any sort of appreciable problem.

Comment: Again see the -1 thing :)
I researched this question and its clear and fully understandable, its useful for me so i asked, still -1.

Comment: @deceze Ahaan .. really ! Thankyou I did'nt knew this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using same if else at every place you can easily refactor like.

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
 $class = "unactivepanel"; 
else 
 $class = "activepanel";
?>
```

now simply do echo $class wherever you need it,like

```
 <section class="panels <?php echo $class;?>unactivepanel" id="Shipping"></section>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i should learn now. Code Refactoring. Thankyou brother.

Answer (score 1):

Tarun is right. Also a switch case will only ever help you when you have multiple possible code blocks that all rely on the value of a single variable. In your case a swtich block would be pointless.

Comment: Ahm. Yes you are right. i.e why i was too confused.